# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'

Tags: typescript

I am contacting the syntax related to TS generalization, I am using two ways to constrain the generalization, but the first writeup reports an error and the second one doesn't, what is the reason for this, thank you for your reply!

typescript version:5.1.6

one way

```
function add<T extends string|number>(a1:T,a2:T) :T{
  return a1+a2
}
add<number>(1,3)
```

two way

```
type addType<T extends string | number> = (a1:T,a2:T)=>T
const add1:addType<string> = (a1,a2)=>{
  return a1+a2
}
add1('1','2')
const add2:addType<number> = (a1,a2)=>{
  return a1+a2
}
add2(3,4)
```

The writing in playground is rather confusing, I hope it doesn't confuse you, the line of code is 220, again I feel your reply!

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/zh/play?ts=5.1.6#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGYCGAtgKYBcA5ABYAeNZANNjHgOakBMADJgL5MQyhIUTJigBPAA5E4SACqTpacVJAAzGYgDcIwdA1sSG+VLRYc+YuWq0GOFuy7cRASzBQiAJ1V5g0gJIASkRQAK4eYGa4hKTQHq7MtkysJGAhBPCePCLK0qohYMaKMAAUFjFQcWAJ9ilpGR4AlCgAfIHBYWA64Hp5YACMJL2FqCVldPZNzZEe7eEYjObRiXasjE5OmAA2wUweHiT5ANZgIADuYCOc2nh7I2QAzBxkLm6e3r4wfgAyRFVQFPMcNs-hRaulMhscp8AGL5H4XNDFYEkb6-Zj-SapcEeLpCGC9eEo2FgeEjJG-SbTWYXYEAOmB6IoWUwBN+xTInDIDRZcLZAG0+nQ2HR7nQALrc1lgYqRBn-EgAFkc3MwulgNw8AGUKiRYvE+WKRnyyH16ByzfcyGLVd0QNt6SBmMUNdrGjbIHaiA6nS6KjBXNA8GBfGoYABBPZ4MQqqHACiHYaIhCIA5gY5nMCYuqeGAAHxgeqquL0ccOfiEQd8JFLiZKycpjGcqmKOVDydQKBQZELzC5kRwM1Cc2T9LR-zWjeb7YDUErRFDEY8UYa-Zgg46GlHIInOCbxWnFeD8-UAHkkERgFAVwsYNtYMie3ncNmPCMALR9BZ7shyihkf0XPWq5Ar8Iwjr+fAFhU8RPli9Q7mu1K3r8CGMOucyfhspbloGR7FAKQoinQCoSiIogKPi+SyLIAA8sgwEQVDuGAAAm-A9rmcGeM0ZJYiQsiTLIxawEMgxUbRXEeDxiJYg2A5IViWRqpRBQGEMtE9tJoxpHJiFDhcikbAA9EZMCACVygCTyoA3j6ANHq5FSEwtaSfZ0jwLWPYuQIHggBAEC1nghQAGRuQoIgmQI3SwMAMDVt5vm1n0bD3GRrjuF4Pj+GGkRlLq0FVNoKykM5GypW8GWfAAQpEeAsSxMy+bllTMMyymuKoIAomGgV+BVqDZdEVg2IwNScIkNV1UQDVkBIACOEDPMZpnAJseC+TAAAKngQOAWDhYslg9toe1JEVL6YMdaoeCEl4gB4pQDT24zJJJ17HTg-zOBAtJlCMZRHaZODvRQn20vYIz2P9gNOOFGx4PAsQ+FFK1rZtHjbREw3wxUiNRAdeXMAVTBY0ul4nWC8F2MTOMQFGABy0TFA0JAAG4gM4LEtcj-C00Qpyo+jDFMb8bEbVtO2MJd11QLdxQSCE8CbM40U5Y9csK0rZMvauEAhFId3cjgTg4DTYj08QjOrronreuyiX3HbXIThsmClelHx+Pz4v7eUTWEzUkl+7V9UQI18SMCbZukIzLSs+zLWRbgvOewiienDAPN82L0qUDQNicNyYBJ1ntIRwzKrLat-B+H4BASMn-q19sxBuFXyeRJLN13WrivKw9+N0N3Gv+y+dAwIP0XjcHodVNegMwB9X0-Wgf03gvoOsODrCE0DIOT5N-BoHvvmE0bBZ02Xq7oRcAAGAAk6Br2U3Bvm+99r0fEDcNfCEm2GrAWzeK29pNiOltklR2ht454mcDXOuWdyztV+rzT4sDk7smsFQego1ppzUdjA2uycEEgBLufc2KoXavDdv4NujAVb92Gs9Ee4cox-yjpMWOHNnbhWUr-VgxIUT10RA2C6tpgGgJNElB23IYbuj0HrdGRCBgeyziMfqlgyCIFzvQBhDgxpB33uQWa81Eil0sNHKYgDRFehAU6CRloDYwG4CYlhyRzGWysTbO2Dj1jZAogAYWJLWZ008EjwBCXQZmIT2Fsw5rIqK-CAlUQooiPAdB4ARN0kA6x4i7YO3GGkjJzJXbvH8NCIMVB4h0UFLINgFjvb8UFDo-ibAoE9CDAADXiEScplTHqSS0mo0gOchqFRIJwZkUIJA3EIH5BQdEtJCTiWPaZBAQ5TKXKswoNF+mXC4J5Xo60VmzKkPMskNxmD8QaKgZoiylkHJuAQVaMV7kbOOUQbZL4tLOg8MwXSV9djNS4aZXol5nDgCYLVZ0AxJLjAMC9cmmRwogqgGCi440oXhLwAYHsTMPLnWBfkUF4L0V4AGEGMQsKSDkqZuS3aAM9IblJQAaixfixxYVTLor6BwIUHBpGcshSaJ4dAORPHITyYMKLiW1TooLZiIsOL9IxbISlAkYqyCpPpJgfQWUtKcOND52JmjFEFPcGMFFxpbPooxeV7F8awU+WcgYKqsWXJaEJZS40yW1S2ZpJ1sK-lIVJSgVl+rap9FtmaNgjtPW1QMJauZOyUmCixYGrVwbQ2YHGmwYoooFQNCAA)

I don't quite understand the difference between the two ways of writing it

Comment: Is the equal sign in the second code block a typo?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the reply, I made a mistake and have changed it now

Comment: Because <number>+<string> is not legal.  This would be OK - `function add<T extends string|number>(a1:string,a2:T) :string`

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the two ways is that the first uses a generic function while the second uses functions whose types are applied generics, but they are not themselves generic.

It might be insightful to see that

```
function add<T extends string>(a1:T,a2:T) :T{
  return a1 + a2
}
```

and

```
function add<T extends number>(a1:T,a2:T) :T{
  return a1 + a2
}
```

will also give you errors. `add<"hello">("hello", "hello")` would be an example of a type violation.